# Unknown error after apt upgrade (xserver-xorg-video-dummy:amd64 missing). Fans rev up/down continuously

Tags: nvidia, xorg, fan

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on an Intel NUC 9 Pro with a Nvidia Quadro P2200

My main problem is that my fans rev up and down on a continuous loop even when the computer is idle. Temps are fine so this should not be happeing and only started after running `apt upgrade` which included a lot of updates including many nvidia packages. Everything seems to work fine aside from the fans spinning up.

When booting up I get these error messages:

> [ 0.657529] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working,
> polling instead

After reboot I get a notification in the top bar stating:

> An error occured. please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("The cache has no package named 'xserver-xorg-video-dummy:amd64'")'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

When I run `apt-cache search video-dummy` it returns:

```
xserver-xorg-video-dummy - X.Org X server -- dummy display driver
xserver-xorg-video-dummy-hwe-18.04 - Transitional package for xserver-xorg-video-dummy-hwe-18.04
```

`nvidia-smi` returns:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P2200        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 52%   48C    P0    22W /  75W |    218MiB /  5056MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1684      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 88MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2995      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               27MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6166      C   /usr/NX/bin/nxnode.bin             97MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When running `watch -n 2 sensors` no temps go above ≈40 degrees.

What I'm wondering is, might these error messages be related to the problem with the fans? How should I go about fixing the video-dummy error? Is this firmware bug something that needs fixing, google says it can be ignored. How would I fix the problem with the fans? I can't help but wonder if this is related to Nvidia updates.

I'm not an expert so go easy on me ;D Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you tell if it is the GPU fan or the CPU fans?

Comment: No I can't be sure, is there a way I can find out?

Comment: You have the GPU fan speed in your output above.  If you don't have the other fan speeds when running `sensors` then you should run `sensors-detect` to see if it finds fan sensors.

Comment: @rtaft I went into the Nvidia X server settings and turned the GPU fan speed to 0 and the fans are still spinning up/down indicating it's the CPU fans

Comment: @rtaft when running `sensors` I only see temps, no fan speeds or rpm's. When I run `sensors-detect` it only returns `coretemp` and asks if I want to add that to /etc/modules

Comment: when running `sensors-detect` is there anything found in the Super IO section?  Maybe a 'Yes' with an error right below it?

Comment: @rtaft yes there is this line in the Super IO section: `Trying family National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes`
`Found unknown chip with ID 0x5571`